# npm: how to have duplicate dependencies in dev and non-dev

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install

I have a repo that is a dependency of all my main projects. In this repo I have a `dev` branch which we develop on. Can I use this when the production flag isn't set?

I have a `package.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "repo": "git+ssh://git@git.example.com:pack/repo.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "repo": "git+ssh://git@git.example.com:pack/repo.git#dev"
  }
}
```

> npm WARN The package repo is included as both a dev and production dependency.

When I do an `npm install`, it installs the one from the `dependencies`. Is there a way to install the one from `devDependencies` when the production flag isn't set?

Comment: ever get this to work?

Comment: No I did not get this working